# Using spacy's displacy REST microservices on RHEL

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I need to use Spacy services (https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services) for named entity recognition making use of its ent POST request.

Need to know how can I get the service cloned from github started on my localhost on RHEL box so as to make use of something like http://localhost:8000/ent to post my requests.